# Problema com verificações de booleans no JavaScript

Tags: javascript, operadores, booleano

```
var a = '0';
if (!a) console.log('false');
if (a == false) console.log('false 2');
```

Por que o *false* não é exibido mas o *false 2* é?

Comment: Se fosse `0`, os dois apareceriam, mas você está testando string ( `'0'` ). String pra ser `false` precisa estar vazia. Mas quando você compara com `==`, o JS converte o valor da string, e interpreta o zero dentro dela.

Comment: E por que isso acontece? Ambos checam se minha variável é falsa.

Comment: Nao, um é negação, o outro é comparação. Negar uma string é diferente de fazer um "cast" e comparar. É meio esquisito, mas é um problema de design da linguagem. Se você comparar com `===` vai ficar mais esquisito ainda.

Comment: Use sempre `===` a não ser que você tenha certeza do que está fazendo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em JavaScript `'0'` é definido como `true` (qualquer coisa que não seja `false`, 0, "", `null`, `undefined` ou `NaN`, é verdadeiro). Então a primeira expressão nega um verdadeiro e portanto não executa o comando do `if`. Até aí, ok?

O segundo está **convertendo implicitamente a *string* para numérico** (coerção), tornando o valor 0 como operando, um valor que é considerado `false`, conforme mostrando acima, então a comparação é verdadeira.

Porque no operador de igualidade é feita a conversão e no operador de negação não faz a conversão é algo que só pode ser explicado com um "a linguagem definiu assim".

Tem coisas que só o JavaScript faz por você. :)