# Dúvida sobre operador de negação

Tags: javascript, java, característica-linguagem

Por que em Java não é possível utilizar o operador de negação em um objeto como no Javascript? Isso ocorre por que Java é fortemente tipada ou há alguma outra peculiaridade? Pois em Javascript o operador de negação pode ser aplicado em qualquer tipo.

Exemplo:

**Java**

```
String nome = "Renan";

if(!nome){ // erro

} ...
```

**Javascript**

```
let nome = "Renan";

if(!nome) 
   alert("Sem erro");
else
   alert(nome);
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/117354/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/271693/112052)

Answer (score 2):

O tipo `String` no Java é um `objeto`, então ele tenta negar um objeto gerando o erro, mas `javascript` não é fortemente tipado e é possível interpretar uma `string`, se a `string` for vazia por exemplo o retorno será `false` e se ela estiver com alguma valor o retorno será `true`, ou seja ao negar a `string` ele vai ter o seu valor `booleano` e esta valor será negado.

Answer (score 2):

> Isso ocorre por que Java é fortemente tipada?

Não é só porque o Java é fortemente tipado mas porque o Javascript é fracamente tipado,

```
    let nome = "Renan";

if(!nome) 
   alert("Sem erro");
else
   alert(nome);
```

Isso retorna uma expressão booleana, ou seja, 
O valor undefined se comporta como false, quando usado em um contexto booleano. Por exemplo, o código que você deu de exemplo  executa alert(nome) porque a váriavel não é  undefined.

Já isso que você tá tentando fazer em Java ao meu ver nem faz sentido:

```
String nome = "Renan";

if(!nome){ // da erro

} ...
```

Porque o que você tá tentando fazer dentro do if não retorna um boolean, por isso dá o erro.

Comment: Eu sei que não faz sentido, este exemplo é pra explicitar a diferença

Answer (score 0):

Em JS é feita uma comparação booleana com o valor interno, caso seja vazio, ele entende como 0 (zero) ou falso, quando tem algo ele entende como 1 (um) ou verdadeiro.

O Java trata a string como uma string e não como um objeto, portanto a comparação tem que ser feita como o tipo dela (string), para isto usa-se o método `equals()`, este método retorna `true` ou `false` como tu deseja comparar.

Ex.:

```
String nome = "Renan";

if(!nome.equals("")){ // nome NÃO é vazio

} ...
```

Veja a [documentação do Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/comparestrings.html).

Veja rodando [aqui](http://tpcg.io/EBIVSu).

Comment: String é sim um objeto em Java, pois é um tipo construído.

Comment: @renanzin, sim String é uma classe do Java, não um objeto genérico, portanto tu não pode comparar ela de forma booleana, mas sim o seu valor.

Answer (score 0):

No java, o if só verifica uma condição boleana.

```
boolean condicao = true;

if(condicao) {

}...

//agora é possível negar a condição
if(!condicao) {

}...

//para verificar se uma String está vazia pode utiliza o método isEmpty(), que retorna um boolean
String nome = "Renan";
if(nome.isEmpty()) {

}...
```